# R Shiny, how to get observer to execute first?

Tags: r, shiny

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(
    "select_id",
    "Select Name",
    choices = c("A", "B", "C"),
    selected = NULL,
    multiple = TRUE
  ),
  textOutput("select")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "select_id", selected = "A")
  })
  
  output$select <- renderText({
    validate(need(input$select_id, "Nothing selected"))
    input$select_id
  })
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If you execute the above code, you'd notice that for a split second the validate message, `Nothing selected` is printed on the screen before `A` replaced it.

That is because `validate(need(input$select_id, "Nothing selected"))` is ran before `validate(need(input$select_id, "Nothing selected"))`.

How can I fix this?

EDITED:

actually, even this wouldn't work:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(
    "select_id",
    "Select Name",
    choices = c("A", "B", "C"),
    selected = NULL,
    multiple = TRUE
  ),
  textOutput("select")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$select <- renderText({
    updateSelectInput(session, "select_id", selected = "A")
    validate(need(input$select_id, "Nothing selected"))
    input$select_id
  })
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use another reactive value to track your application state. And if you're not yet intialized, then abort any updates

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  initialized = reactiveVal(FALSE)
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "select_id", selected = "A")  
    initialized(TRUE)
  })
  
  output$select <- renderText({
    req(initialized(), cancelOutput = TRUE)
    validate(need(input$select_id, "Nothing selected"))
    input$select_id
  })
}
```

Since everything happens so quickly it's hard to see what's going on. Here's a version that delays the updating of the select for a second.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  initialized = reactiveVal(FALSE)
  updateUI = reactiveVal(FALSE)
  
  observe({
    if (isolate(updateUI())) {
      updateSelectInput(session, "select_id", selected = "A")  
      initialized(TRUE)
    } else {
      updateUI(TRUE)
      invalidateLater(1000, session)
    }
  })
  
  output$select <- renderText({
    req(initialized(), cancelOutput = TRUE)
    validate(need(input$select_id, "Nothing selected"))
    input$select_id
  })
}
```

Comment: what package does the function initialized come from? When I run it, it can't be found.

Comment: It’s not a function. It’s a reactive value that I defined first in the server body. It’s defined before the observe.

Comment: Ok, I see it now. But unfortunately, it did not work. I still see the `Nothing selected` for the first split second of the app

Comment: @code_life I cannot replicate that behavior. I've added a second example that delays the updated. It's makes it clear that the "Nothing selected" part is not displayed before the select is updated. Tested with `shiny_1.5.0`

Comment: my shiny version is `1.4.0.2`. So I guess it doesn't apply